# Are some USB hard drive enclosures unsuitable for system drive use?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, usb-2

I have a number of hard drives in USB 2.0 enclosures. Some of these produce odd but consistent software failures when trying to use them as a Linux system drive. The problem appears to be tied to the USB 2.0 bridge used in the enclosures; the symptoms disappear when the interface is changed.

**Two questions:**

1. **Is this a known issue?** Is there a known incompatibility or deficiency of some of the USB bridges that makes them unsuitable or undependable for use with a system drive ( Linux or any OS)?
2. **Is there a way to check for this issue?** Is there an easy way to determine which USB enclosures can be used for Linux system drives?

The problematic USB interfaces are not dependable in the sense that a distro that works with it now might have a future problem after an update.  I am seeking a way to avoid using those interfaces rather than solve specific identified failures.

**Supplementary information on what I have noticed and tested:**

- **Hard drives are fine:** They test out as perfect even when using the problematic USB enclosures.
- **USB 2.0 interfaces work for storage; not always as system:** All of the USB 2.0 interfaces work properly for basic data storage and with system drives for some Linux distros.  However, some of the interfaces produce odd software failures when used with a system drive for certain Linux distros.
- **Linux kernel/distro seem irrelevant:** Distros that did work were broken by updates when the updates were installed using the problematic interfaces. So the specific distros that do or don’t work is not material.  Tested distros used four different major kernel releases and the issue appears unrelated to that.
- **Examples of problems:** The failures are consistent; the same distros produce the same errors across these interfaces, and different distros produce similar errors. Some symptom examples:

  - **Can’t partition USB 2.0 drives via LiveCD:** Certain distros' LiveDVD failed to partition the drive for installation when a problematic interface was used.
  - **GUI desktop manager doesn’t load:** The USB boot ends at a system prompt.
  - **Drive goes into a “Read Only” state:** Existing root and home partitions become read-only filesystems.

Comment: The linux kernel is constantly being updated and released almost monthly.  The problem could be fixed in a newer version of the kernel.  Please use **uname -r** to determine which kernel version you are using.

Comment: Each tested distro uses a different kernel.  Distros using 3.16 and 3.18 couldn't partition the drive (probably not kernel related).  Debian uses 3.2 and updating  from .51 to .65 triggered a failure.  Fedora uses 3.17.  I don't know the sub-numbers, but V20 worked fine, V21 couldn't be booted.  The kernel update in Debian is definitely what triggered its failure, but I suspect that is an artifact.

Comment: What is actually happening ? I don't see any `dmesg` nor boot errors quoted in your post.

Comment: @AndréDaniel - I added a little information on the nature of the symptoms.  However, they are just wack-a-mole artifacts.  The way to solve all of the various current and potential future symptoms is to use an interface that doesn't cause them in the first place.  My goal is to distinguish the right interfaces.

Comment: Please stop editing so frequently, either to bump your question or even to simply improve. Just let the question be. If it can be solved, answers will come. If not, then that has to be accepted.